# Union of sets and set satisfiability and tautologies

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I was troubled with these two questions:
I have to prove/refute many statements, but only two of which troubled me:

(1) If $A ∪ B$ is satisfiable, then both $A$ and $B$ are satisfiable. 
I know for a fact that the other way around is not correct (the union of two satisfiable sets is not necessarily satisfiable).
I have tried to disprove the statement with many examples, but so far no avail. Moreover, I have tried to prove the statement, yet it does not seem so right.

(2) β is a tautology if and only if for every $α, α ⊢_{} β$. 
I proved the first direction, however, the second one did not go as smoothly.

Comment: Also in this case, I presume that we must have $\alpha \vDash_{CPL} \beta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\omega$ be a propositional evaluation such that $\omega\models A\cup B$. Then, per definition, for any $\alpha\in A\cup B$, we have $\omega\models\alpha$.

Note, that thus

1. For all $\alpha\in A\subseteq A\cup B$: $\omega\models\alpha$, i.e. $\omega\models A$.
2. For all $\alpha\in B\subseteq A\cup B$: $\omega\models\alpha$, i.e. $\omega\models B$.

The key point is here really that if a set is satisfiable, then all formulas in the set are *simultaneously* satisfiable, i.e. there is an evaluation such that all formulas from the set are true in this model.

So if $A\cup B$ is satisfiable, then all formulas from both $A$ and $B$ are satisfiable by at least one model.

---

For the second one, suppose $\alpha\models\beta$ for any $\alpha$. Thus also $\gamma\lor\neg\gamma\models\beta$ for some $\gamma$ (just setting $\alpha=\gamma\lor\neg\gamma$).

Now $\gamma\lor\neg\gamma\models\beta$ means that for every evaluation $\omega$, if $\omega\models\gamma\lor\neg\gamma$, then $\omega\models\beta$. But every evaluation $\omega$ fulfills $\omega\models\gamma\lor\neg\gamma$. Thus, every evaluation $\omega$ fulfills $\omega\models\beta$ and thus $\beta$ is a tautology.

The inverse direction is pretty straightforward as if $\beta$ is a tautology, then $\omega\models\beta$ for any evaluation $\omega$. Thus, for any $\alpha$, if $\omega\models\alpha$, then $\omega\models\beta$ anyway, so $\alpha\models\beta$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is it possible to ask one more question regarding a new language? (A question in which a new logical language is defined)

Comment: @KamalKhalaily I think the best would be to open up a new question for this.